Dim Taillights After Battery Replacement
Recently I bought Duralast Gold battery from autozone and had a mechanic install it real quick, since he was also doing a brake flush for me. After the new battery, my taillights became very much dim, if it was one of them I’d figure bulb just went out, but all the taillight went dim.
The instrument/dashbord interior light also went dim, but I found a way to brighten it up.
The taillight remains an issue, any advice?
Edit: With the new battery, the car starts up perfectly with no starting issue, plus it’s tightened not loose at all
PS I found out it’s Both the taillight and the brake light too that are issue

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked the voltage at the battery (engine off) to see what it reads?

Hello, the battery reads 12.6 v engine off and when engine on 13.8 v

One thing I’m curious about from online research I read about coding battery before installing it? I never saw this irl and never even heard about such

Honda would not be one of those requiring the battery be coded. Very few cars do this, though it is an actual "thing". The voltages you stated are right in the ballpark of where they should be. Your problem is very strange, that's for sure.

To add some more context, I had a brake fluid flush done by the mechanic before he went on to replace the battery, and also I noticed he left the car running Idle while he took the old battery out and installed new one, not sure if that might’ve caused it? After battery is removed and replaced, I know the radio code should be reset, but it didn’t need reset for some reason, seems like it remembered.

For future reference, if you have any choice, don't go back to this mechanic. One of the side effects of removing the battery with the car running is it can cause an electrical short which can blow out ALL of the electronics in the vehicle (worst case scenario). This is one thing you DO NOT DO with an alternator. If you're trying to maintain codes, you keep a small 12v battery around you can tie in while you change out the battery. I have several of them in my garage for this exact purpose. Now that you said this, it may actully be what has caused your issue.

So I had a different guy who is an auto electrician, small business mechanic and showed him the issue, he confirmed to me that the battery being removed while car is on is most likely what actually caused electrical short and killed my taillights, we replaced the bulbs and it’s now working fine.
